# timer job not applicable ignoring job definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

We have created custom timer job in share point 2010.but we are getting error

**job definition "job name", id  ed6b4720-67c3-4bbc-aa46-e98a2aa67202 not applicable, ignoring**

We are unable to find out error for the same in share point log.

Its web level timer job . and farm architecture is 2 WFE and 1 application server.

Comment: When are you getting this error? Is this web level or web application level feature?

Comment: Web application level feature.After activating feature

Comment: is this the full error message? Have you tried restarting the timer service?

Comment: what is you JobLock Type?

Comment: Yes this the full error message.we restarted timer service once we deployed wsp. but with no success.

Comment: what is you JobLock Type?

Comment: SPJobLockType.Job

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment on this question so posting an answer.

This issue is related to uninstalling older version of same timer job. If this timer job is feature enabled then try to disable and re-enable it.

If you are going to re-install it then disable it first before reinstallation.

Comment: yes we tried but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try execute the script bellow as Farm Admin (using SharePoint Management Shell):

```
$appServer = "put SharePoint Application Server Name here"
$spFarm = Get-SPFarm
$ts = $spFarm.TimerService.Instances | ?{$_.server -match $appServer}
$ts.AllowContentDatabaseJobs = $true
$Tts.Update()
```